# Object Detection - Image Cropping

Tags: object-detection

I am working on my first object detection project. My goal is to detect US postal mailing address on envelopes and letters.

My training data is a collection of images ranging in size and amount of content. Some of my images are 1700 x 2800 px letters with lots of content (logos, sidebars, postal address), while others are 100 x 300 px images that only contain the postal address. From my research, it seems that 300px and smaller is a good size for object detection. I tried to resize the large images and make them smaller, but the content became very distorted.

My question is, if my goal is to detect just the postal address, can I crop the 1700x2800 images down to the postal address to make the images smaller and retain clarity? If this is not recommended, is there a recommend approach to downsizing my large images without losing resolution?